# How to measure algorithmically side lobes in real data

Tags: signal-analysis, python, signal-detection, peak-detection, measurement

I want to measure algorithmically the following parameters in a given FFT data (real numbers).

- peak side lobe levels
- side lobe levels
- side lobes nulls

The following image illustrates parameters I need.

[image]

How I can compute those values using Matlab or Python?

Answer (score 1):

Zero pad your FFT (append zeros) such that you get more samples of the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT). The DTFT would give you the sidelobes and roll-off that you want to see (specifically for your diagram you would zero pad an input that is all ones, or an input that is any constant value).